# In postgreSQL how do I view column names?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am working with a database that has a few tables. Currently when I run a command such as `wizard=# SELECT * FROM professor;`

I am returned

```
2 | Severus Snape            |            32
3 | Dolores Umbridge         |            32
4 | Bathsheda Babbling       |            34
```

for the purpose of writing more detailed queries I would like to know how to turn on headers (in SQLite this would be `.headers on`), and how to view the schema (in SQLite this would be `.shema table_name`)

Comment: check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table) post

Comment: Displaying headers is the default, but you can turn it back on using the `\t` command in psql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Maybe there is something in your `.psqlrc` that changes the display from the default format.